# Car is making buzzing noise but wont turn over

Tags: starting, ignition, peugeot, peugeot-307

I have a Peugeot 307. All the lights are working, stereo etc when turning the ignition key to on, but when I turn the key to the start position it does not do anything but makes a constant buzzing noise which I can hear ( *from under the bonnet* ) coming from either the battery or the fuse box.

The battery is only 12 months old and all electrics are working. I can't see it being the battery ( *I'm not a mechanic so I'm just guessing this* ) I used the car this morning  and it started with no problems, but a few hours later when I went to start it to take my daughter to the hospital and again now it wouldn't start!

I was given a push start and it bump started that way but after I turned the engine off I tried starting it again but it won't start. The emissions light is on the dash when it won't start, but when I bump started it and got the engine running the light went out.

Now it wont start again, the light is constantly on!  I'm a single mum with a disabled child and I don't know any gentleman that knows about cars who can take a look at it for me and I can't get it to a garage or afford to have it done.

I'm hoping and praying someone on here could help me with some advice please on what the problem may be? I cant get around without my car so now I'm housebound. Thank you

Comment: Try charging the battery and see if the problem subsides.  It sounds to me like the battery is low.

Comment: To go with the above, on some vehicles when the battery is low, trying the starters operates a relay which provide power to the starter motor. The starter motor puts a large load on the battery, and so it no longer has enough power to operate the relay. So you get a rapid bussing noise and the relay activates / deactivates. This can be triggered by a battery on its last legs, or a charging system that has failed (so isn't charging the battery).